# User defined variables wont recognize that its own type list IS the type

Tags: recursion, types, ocaml, algebraic-data-types

For some reason, I'm getting errors claiming that `distribute((AndC t),p)` is a `cnf` instead of a `cnf list`... except a `cnf list` IS a type of `cnf`. Why doesn't OCaml recognize this will provide a list eventually?

The trouble spot is lines 11-12.

```
type cnf
  = AtomC of signed_atom
  | AndC of cnf list    
  | OrC of cnf * cnf

let rec distribute : cnf * cnf -> cnf = 

  let rec aux = function
    | AndC [], _
    | _, AndC [] -> AndC []
    | AndC (h::t), p -> AndC( distribute(h,p) :: distribute((AndC t),p) )
    | p, AndC (h::t) -> AndC( distribute(p,h) :: distribute(p,(AndC t)) )
    | p, q -> OrC(p, q)
  in aux
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A value of the form `AndC xxx` is not a list. It's a value of type `cnf`, and it *contains* a list. But it's not a list itself.

A declaration like yours defines one new type `cnf`, and three new *value constructors*, `AtomC`, `AndC`, `OrC`. Value constructors (as in the name) are used to construct values. They aren't types.

Every value of type `cnf` will be constructed by one of the three constructors. So a list of `cnf` values is not a `cnf` value itself. The `AndC` is required.

**Update**

If you define this function:

```
let mycons cnf andc =
    match andc with
    | AndC cnfs -> cnf :: cnfs
    | _ -> [cnf] (* Not possible *)
```

You can replace `::` with `mycons` like this:

```
AndC( mycons (distribute (h,p)) (distribute ((AndC t), p)) )
```

(I haven't tested this, but I think the idea is OK. The claim is that the second call to `distribute` is guaranteed to return an `AndC` value.)

**Update 2**

You can define `distribute` directly without `aux` like this:

```
let rec distribute : cnf * cnf -> cnf = function
| AndC [], _
| _, AndC [] -> AndC []
(* Rewrite these ...
| AndC (h::t), p -> AndC( distribute(h,p) :: distribute((AndC t),p) )
| p, AndC (h::t) -> AndC( distribute(p,h) :: distribute(p,(AndC t)) )
 ... *)
| p, q -> OrC(p, q)
```

Comment: Ohhhh so returning an AndC [ ] doesn't count as a list and therefore :: AndC [ ] wont work. So I need a base condition with a list, or a better way of appending the head element to the rest?

Comment: I think this is right. You could define your own replacement for `::` to make a `cnf list` from a `cnf` and a value `AndC (...)`. It would take the list out of the `AndC` and *then* do the cons.

Comment: Im not sure I understand. How would I make a cnf list maker without using :: ?

Comment: Sorry, it's just an idea. I'll expand my answer.

Comment: This gives the error message "This kind of expression is not allowed as right-hand side of `let rec'"

I had tried something similar before and kept getting the same error as well

Comment: This is a separate problem. Since you don't call `aux` I would just define `distribute` directly.